# EPPlus Modify Range-Selection Chart Excel

Tags: excel, charts, epplus

I am using EPPlus in my project to create an excel report. To generate report, I use template that contain empty chart. I just need to modify range selection the empty chart.

Example, in one report, the chart only need 3 rows of data. But in another report, the chart need 5 rows.
Can I do that?

Hope my english doesn't confusing you :)

Thanks for advance.